# Flutter_Stripe: Apple Pay and Android Pay true does nothing

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, applepay, android-pay

So I have configure the plugin to be able to pay with stripe with a credit card. When I turn on Apple Pay and Android Pay to true, nothing changes. What extra configuration do I have to apply? From documentation I am not able to do by myself

Using the following payment sheet without extra configuration:

```
// 2. initialize the payment sheet
  await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
    paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
      // Main params
      paymentIntentClientSecret: data['paymentIntent'],
      merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
      // Customer params
      customerId: data['customer'],
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: data['ephemeralKey'],
      // Extra params
      applePay: true,
      googlePay: true,
      style: ThemeMode.dark,
      primaryButtonColor: Colors.redAccent,
      billingDetails: billingDetails,
      testEnv: true,
      merchantCountryCode: 'DE',
    ),
  );
```

and when PaymenSheet appears, I expect a button to select android pay or apple pay based on the platform.

Probably missing basic configuration, but I am not able to find any tutorial o configuration for flutter_stripe

Comment: Have you activated Google Pay and Apple Pay wallets as payment methods in your Stripe dashboard?  

https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods

I know it's obvious but just in case.

Comment: Yes, it is activated